# How to get Unique DeviceID from Xamarin IOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a requirement wherein I **should not** allow the user to **install** my app in **more than 1 device**. This is an enterprise application and I distributed this using Enterprise developer account. Based on the Google search I use **IdentifierForVendor** to get unique device ID, but this doesn't seem to work now as when the user uninstalls and installs the new/same version of the app in the same device again, it returns new DeviceID. Now I am back to my old question - How to find a DeviceID for IOS?

What I think is a possible approach is to deactivate the DeviceID when the user uninstalls the application. But I am not sure how to achieve this as there are no cycle/function calls when the app is uninstalled.

Comment: The normal approach is to add a UUID to the device keychain. This will survive across app uninstall/re-install but not across device resets.  You will need a manual process to unregister the user's device when they replace their device or erase it.  Best practice for enterprise app distribution is to do so via the MDM, limiting the user to only installing it on devices you know about and control.  In this instance the one device limit should not be an issue.

Answer (score 5):

[Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620059-identifierforvendor) says if all the apps from the same vendor is uninstalled from the device, then at the time of new installation of any app from that vendor will take new **IdentifierForVendor**.

So I would suggest store this unique id in **Keychain** and whenever you open the app  check if there is any unique id stored in keychain if not then generate one and keep it there.

If app in uninstalled also , the key will be still there.

After you re-install the app , when you access the key in keychain it'll be still there.

This way you can achieve your objective of uniquely tracking a device.

Talking of keychain , it's worthwhile to take a look at [Xamarin.Essentials Nuget](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials).It provides many cross platform features including keychain.

Hope this helps.